# Add div to other ID div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have a code that I open in modal window:

```
 contentStr += '<div>Lorem Ispum</div><button>Add to timeline</button></div>';

            $(contentStr).dialog({
              modal:true
          });
```

Now I want when I click on `button` Add to timeline to add: `'<div id="new">place.name</div>'`
into `div ID bottom` but with margin left `var "N"`

How I can do that with jquery?

Comment: Put up a fiddle please. Or atleast dump your code here

Comment: http://jsbin.com/UNuRexA/28

Comment: so first click on submit, then on marker on map and then on button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you meant you have a `var N` somwhere you want to apply it to margin left:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#bottom').append($('<div id="new">place.name</div>').css('marginLeft',N+'px'));
});
```

Some word of advise, this jquery is really basic, next time do some research please and show here what you found and where you struggle.

- http://api.jquery.com/css/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.marginLeft {
    margin-left: Npx;
}
</style>
<script> 
$.('button').click(function(){
     $('div#buttom').html( $('div#buttom').html+'<div class="marginLeft" id="new">place.name</div>');
 });
<script>
```

Comment: I might be beneficial to define styles in a style tag instead of mixing it with the code above.